# Trying to unhide UITextView from behind keyboard

Tags: xcode, swift

I am using the code below to unhide UITextFields. It works great until I try to  unhide a UITextView. It crashes with an error of trying to unwrap a nil value. My question is what do I need to implement to make the UITextView unhide like the UITextFields? Or do I need to use something beside a UITextView to allow a paragraph style input?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var notesInput: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var activeTextField: UITextField!
// MARK: - View
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textField1.delegate = self
    self.textField2.delegate = self

 //   self.textField3.delegate = self
 //   self.textField4.delegate = self
 //   self.textField5.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.unregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
}

// MARK: - Keyboard

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    let center:  NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func unregisterFromKeyboardNotifications () {
    let center:  NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
func keyboardWasShown (notification: NSNotification) {
    let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let kbSize = (info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue() as CGRect!).size

    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    var aRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextField.frame.origin) ) {
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.activeTextField.frame, animated: true)
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
func keyboardWillBeHidden (notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

// MARK: -  Text Field

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = nil
}
```

Comment: First Implement UITextViewDelegate. Also put the code of your keyboardWasShown , keyboardWillBeHidden,textFieldDidBeginEditing,textViewDidBeginEditing.

Comment: @NimishaPatel The implementing of UITextViewDelegate fixed my original error. But I get an unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value for the line of   "if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextField.frame.origin) { self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.activeTextField.frame, animated: true)"

Comment: This is because `activeTextField` is of type UITextField.That is work perfectly for all UITextField but when you used UITextView its type is different.